# how can I fix this scrollbar? cant use html

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'm on a site where you are allowed to customize a profile, but you can only touch the css.
I've managed okay but I have a problem with the [scrollbar here](http://puu.sh/b2HPI/09250c89ef.jpg). It is going out of boundaries because it is in a div box with border radius on.
How could i fix this? to either make it smaller or pushed away from the side. just as long as it doesnt go out of the div border.

Sorry for no jsfiddle.

Comment: without code and no chance of writing HTML, it's absolutely impossible to give you a solution, unless someone here has telepathic superpowers

Comment: @Ryan just seeing the screen I can tell you only one thing. wrap all the `avatar icons` in  a div and then use `overflow-y:scroll` with some `min-height`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have a container element, with an inner element that holds your icons.  You cannot clip the scrollbar corners, but there are a few things you can try to fix this visually.

Firstly, for the container element, you need to make sure that you have set its CSS 'overflow-y' property to 'scroll':

```
    .container {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Then, you can try getting rid of the border radius altogether by doing this:

```
    .container {
      border-radius: 0;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

Or, you can adjust the 'border-radius' and increase the 'border' to give the appearance that the scrollbar is properly nested inside of the container and no longer going outside of its bounds:

```
    .container {
      border: 7px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

I've written a [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/jacefarm/pen/vhyif) for you.